# Rough idle - second Hand 2016 Totyota Fortuner with Petrol 2.7 L 2TR-FE I4 VVT-i

Tags: engine, toyota, troubleshooting

Want to buy a second Hand Totyota Fortuner with Petrol 2.7 L 2TR-FE I4 VVT-i, with only 32.000 km, but the idle is rough and oscilates enough to notice both on the instrumentation board and also physically it rocks the car.

when switching on the AC, while idle, the increased load reduces the rocking of the car, but the instrumentation board still shows oscilation.

The strange thing is that the current owner says "it is only for lack of scheduled maintenance and sparks plugs change" but why He didn't do it already ?

I do not know how long this car has had this problem, can this be a chronic issue or could this have caused damage to the engine ?

I don't want to buy a visit card to the mechanic.

Answer (score 1):

I'd walk away. As you say,if it just needs maintenance, why hasn't he done it already. Lack of scheduled maintenance can also lead to extra wear on various components, leading to more trouble later on.

Leave it, find a different one that has been maintained properly.